# how to assign the date and time value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I want to assign current date and time to field **`Rfleet_Protocol_Application_Date__c`** which datatype is **`date/time`**

Eg:  `Rfleet_Protocol_Application_Date__c =29/5/2016 2:28 PM`

I tried in this way. But the value is not getting assigned.

**javascript:**

```
var newRecords = [];
var c = new sforce.SObject("Rfleet_Car_Set__c");
c.id = "{!Rfleet_Car_Set__c.Id}";
alert(new Date());
c.Rfleet_Protocol_Application_Date__c = new Date();
newRecords.push(c);
```

In alert am getting the current date and time.But am not able to assign the value. am getting the error as below !!

[image]

Please guide me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date object that javascript uses has a different format than the one used by Salesforce. You have to convert the format. Here is a [dev forum link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009BDIIA2) which discuses about the same issue.

Code snippet from the link:

```
var today = new Date();

function fixTime(time){
    if(time < 10) {time = "0" + time};
    return time;
}

function fixDate(date){
  var Month = fixTime(date.getMonth() + 1);
  var Day = fixTime(date.getDate());
  var UTC = date.toUTCString();
  var Time = UTC.substring(UTC.indexOf(':')-2, UTC.indexOf(':')+6);
  var Minutes = fixTime(date.getMinutes());
  var Seconds = fixTime(date.getSeconds());
  return date.getFullYear() + "-" + Month + "-" + Day + "T" + Time;
}

c.Rfleet_Protocol_Application_Date__c = fixDate(today);
```

Comment: hi@Saroj bera Is there any another way to assign the date in one line ?